# Keep environment changes from a Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, environment, python-3.7

I have a script in a subprocess that changes the environment that must be used later.

Something like this (though it wouldn't necessarily use the shell, it just seems a simple example):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> d = dict()
>>> d
{}
>>> subprocess.run("export foo=bar", shell=True, env=d)
CompletedProcess(args='export foo=bar', returncode=0)
>>> d
{'foo':'bar'}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not without hacks or workarounds. Some ideas are listed in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372627/is-it-possible-to-pass-environment-variables-from-child-to-parent-in-user-space (and in the questions referenced there).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was worried about.